# Double Byte Character File Names Not Displayed Correctly

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, double-byte

I have a pdf file named "**ロケールストリングのキャッシュ最適化-v3-20160202_1047.pdf**".

On using google tag manager to get the file name from the download URL, I get the value as "**%E4%BE%9B%E7%B5%A6%E8%A8%88%E7%94%BB-v3-20160202_1047.pdf**". I'm using javascript to fetch the file names in Google Tag Manager.

Is there a way in Javascript to make sure that the file name stays in the given language while the data is being sent to Google Analytics ?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. If we have the file name as "%E4%BE%9B%E7%B5%A6%E8%A8%88%E7%94%BB-v3-20160202_1047.pdf", we can get back the file name ("ロケールストリングのキャッシュ最適化-v3-20160202_1047.pdf") by using encodeURIComponent and decodeURIComponent in tandem.

```
    var encodeUri = encodeURIComponent(filename)
    filename = decodeURIComponent(encodeUri);
```